# Which Link-List Would be the Best to create a Priority queue in terms of memory and time complexity?

Tags: performance, data-structures

In doubly link list, Singly Link list and circular link list, which can be used for most efficient implementation of priority queue.

Comment: This is a question about neither Java nor C.  Untagging them both.

Answer (score 1):

A priority queue (also called heap) is a totally different data structure compared to a list and therefore none of your candidates is "the best".